# image_path shows duplicate assets folder in path with raty plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

For `<%= image_path('star-half-big.png') %>`

I am seeing: `http://localhost:3000/assets//assets/star-half-big.png`

I have confirmed that the image is available at `/assets/star-half-big.png`

Any idea why rails is generating paths like this, and how to fix?

Comment: In development.rb are you setting a `config.assets.prefix = "/assets/"`? That could cause this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put the image under `app/assets/images/` directory.

And, then try it using `image_url`:

```
<%= image_url('star-half-big.png') %>
```

Also, make sure you don't have `config.assets.prefix = "/assets/"` in your config file.

Comment: Hi I do not have `config.assets.prefix` set, my images are in `app/assets/images/`, and  `<%= image_url('star-half-big.png') %>` renders `http://localhost:3000/assets/http://localhost:3000/assets/star-half-big.png`

Comment: Just to make sure, what version of Rails are you using? Most likely, there is some config setting in your project that's doing it.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that in your development.rb you have an asset_host config set.
Comment it out if so.

```
# config.action_controller.asset_host = "localhost:3000/assets/"
```

Comment: Unfortunately not that either

Comment: @Abram, I apologize for sounding so redundant, but did you also check that these configs are appropriately set in application.rb too? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've realized my mistake. I had for `path: '/assets/'` set in `$.fn.raty.defaults = {}` inside of **raty.js**

I now have `path: '../'` in `$.fn.raty.defaults = {}` and in my **views**:

```
starHalf : '<%= image_path('star-half-big.png') %>',
starOff  : '<%= image_path('star-off-big.png') %>',
starOn   : '<%= image_path('star-on-big.png') %>'
```